# libgdx selectbox fit content size

Tags: libgdx

I try to create a selectbox that adapts its width to its content. The JavaDoc states: `The preferred size of the select box is determined by the maximum text bounds of the items and the size of the SelectBox.SelectBoxStyle.background.`, so it should happen automatically.

If I add the selectbox it doesn't show any content and has only the minimal size of the `9Patch` used for the `background`. The text is only visible if I set the width manually.

Do I have to enable this functionality somehow?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it.

After adding the items you have to call `pack()`

```
    SelectBox<String> sb = new SelectBox<>(skin);
    sb.setItems("Hello World", "FooBarBaz", "FizzBuzz");
    sb.pack();
    stage.addActor(sb);
```